# Is this a good way to catch bots?

Tags: php

Is this method sufficient?

```
<?php

// User pressed "Register"
if (!empty($_POST['name']) && $_POST['email']) {


    if (!empty($_POST['antispam'])) 
        exit("bye");

    }

?>

<form>

<input type="hidden" name="antispam" value="" />

Accname: <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="" />

......

</form>
```

Comment: "honeypot" means a site that is set up specifically to entice spam bots to come and visit with the purpose of discovering more about who they are and how they operate.  I don't think that's what you're aiming for here is it?

Comment: @Paolo - A "honeypot" in this sense is merely an enticing form field where you try and capture spambot input on a field that should otherwise be left blank as it has been hidden from a user's view by CSS.

Comment: Most bots I have used load the actual webpage into the bot's own browser so it see's everything a real browser does, they also can set a speed between actions, so IMO bot's are almost impossible to stop, myspace couldn't stop them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all basic sense of the idea, sure. Only thing I would recommend for your simple implementation is that most spam scanners that you're trying to block out look for fields titled "username", "name", "user", etc ..

So, isntead of naming your honeypot "antispam" I would name it "username" or something similar that does not conflict with your existing form.

Answer (score 2):

probably the best name for a form-field designed to trigger a spam bot would be `url`

The chances of a bot parsing the html for `type=text` attributes  or `textarea` tag a and ignoring all others are quite reasonable.

Your chances of trapping a spambot can be improved with a few extra lines of code:

**styles.css**:

```
#commentUrl {
    display: none;
}
```

**script.js**:

```
function setFlag() {
    document.getElementById('commentUrl').value = 'Javascript check ok';
}
```

**form.html**:

```
<form onsubmit="setFlag();" method="post" action="comment.php">
    <label for="commentName">Accname:</label>
      <input type="text" id="commentName" name="comment_name" value="" />

    <label for="commentEmail">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" id="commentEmail" name="comment_email" value="" />

    <label for="commentUrl">Url:</label>
      <input type="text" id="commentUrl" name="comment_url" value="http://" />
</form>
```

**comment.php**:

```
<?php

   if ($_POST['comment_url'] <> 'Javascript check ok' && $_POST['comment_url'] <> 'http://') {
       // Let's increase their server load.
       header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '/', 307); 
   }
?>
```

Because you use three different languages you improve the chances of catching the spammer considerably.
You could improve the javascript by dynamically appending the `<link rel="stylesheet"` dynamically to the DOM for example.

Comment: a bit unfriendly for visitors without Javascript though.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend making the input type hidden or let it have something with "spam" in it. The best way would be to give it a neutral name ("message" maybe) and hide it from the page via css. Additionally I would measure how long it took to fill out the form (as this will be very fast or very slow by robots) by adding a timestamp field (and again give it a neutral name and maybe encode it).

Comment: Most bots I have used load the actual webpage into the bot's own browser so it see's everything a real browser does, they also can set a speed between actions, so IMO bot's are almost impossible to stop, myspace couldn't stop them

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a hidden field as bots might be looking for only elements of `type="text"`.  The naming should be something common but something you have no use for, examples being:

- firstname
- lastname
- email
- username
- password
- bio
- description

You should change your input from

```
<input type="hidden" name="antispam" value="" />
```

to something more along the lines of

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="" style="display:none; height: 0; width: 0; border: none; background: transparent; margin: 0; padding: 0;" />
```